# ios UIActivityViewController not attaching images sending text messages

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'm using UIActivityViewController to share in Facebook,email,twitter and texting. Everything works just fine with the exception of texting. When I select the texting option it doens't attach the image to the text. Here is my code:

```
NSMutableArray *tmp=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[tmp addObject:tmpImage];
[tmp addObject:@"Hello"];
NSArray *activityItems =[NSArray arrayWithArray:tmp];
UIActivityViewController *activityVC=[[UIActivityViewController alloc]initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];
[self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

any of you knows why is not attaching the image to the texting part?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

In app MMS (multi-media messaging) is not supported for the current iOS, only SMS is supported.

Possible solutions include:

•copying the image to the clipboard and having the user paste it into the messaging text box manually. (You can open a texting app that supports mms via the URI scheme "sms://" (just load that URL)

•loading the images into the eMail application and sending the eMail as a text message to either one of your servers that can sort out the issue, to the iMessages eMail address, or to the sms/mms eMail address (ex. a phone number of 404-345-6789 with AT&T could receive a text message if an eMail was sent to 4043456789@txt.att.net, all major carriers have an eMail address for every phone number).